# Spotify api 1.x Disable seek/repeat/shuffle/rewind/ff

Tags: spotify

in the api 0.x it was possible to do smth like this

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi();
sp.trackPlayer.setContextCanSkipPrev(playlist.uri, false);
sp.trackPlayer.setContextCanSkipNext(playlist.uri, false);
sp.trackPlayer.setContextCanShuffle = false;
sp.trackPlayer.setContextCanRepeat = false;
```

However I could not figure out how to do that in the api 1.x

Some Spotify apps (soundrop for example) disable the seek/repeat/shuffle/rewind/ff buttons
so that should be possible

Comment: I agree, I don't see where that is possible.  Either its an oversight, or they've decided not to allow that any more.  I saw on the blog that the old API will stop working end of March 2014 (http://devnews.spotify.com/2013/12/17/deprecation-of-spotify-apps-api-0-x/)

Comment: Well it is definitely possible since the new Soundrop app does that!
There is actually a static method in the [Playlist object](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-playlist.html) called **enforceRules** which is veeery likely to be the one I'm looking for. However the documentation generously states "TODO: Documentation needed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a temporary playlist with a single track and use the [`enforceRules`](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-playlist.html#enforceRules) function:

```js
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {
  var tempName = 'temp' + (new Date()).getTime();
  models.Playlist.createTemporary(tempName).done(function(playlist) {
    playlist.enforceRules('stream');
    playlist.load('tracks').done(function(loadedPlaylist) {
      var track = models.Track.fromURI('spotify:track:7B1Dl3tXqySkB8OPEwVvSu');
      loadedPlaylist.tracks.add(track);
      models.player.playContext(loadedPlaylist, 0);
    });
  });
});
```

Doing so, it automatically disables the skip buttons.

At the moment, it seems the documentation for the API is missing the description of this function.

Comment: Thanks that fits my current needs. However what if I'd like to keep the back/ff buttons active while disabling the seek gauge.